# Receiving "Failed to retrieve projects error" after installing and logging into RapidAPI Client extension in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, rapidapi

After installing and logging into the RapidAPI Client extension on VSCode I am receiving and error "Failed to retrieve projects error".

Screenshots attached: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWplE.png); [login and sync confirm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7P17.png)

I am unable to create a new project in VSCode that will sync to my RapidAPI Studio even though it says I have "signed in and can start syncing". for background I am on a mac and am pretty new at this so any input is appreciated. Apologies in advance if I've missed something obvious or explained poorly.